# How to develop simple DAPP for banking using ethereum ganache and simple html UI?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, metamask, ganache

I want to develop basic DAPP for banking which has functionality as withdraw, deposit, getBalance using ganache ethereum with simple UI.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn how to develop a dapp, here is a good quickstart: [Truffle-Pet shop](https://www.trufflesuite.com/tutorials/pet-shop).

It includes every essential part in developing a dapp, like truffle, ganache, smart contract, and frontend.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

here is what you are looking for [Simple Solidity Smart Contract](https://www.codementor.io/rogargon/exercise-simple-solidity-smart-contract-for-ethereum-blockchain-m736khtby)

Comment: please dont just reply with a link. The content should be in right here in stackoverflow.